# JS/JQuery - Firefox - prevent Ctrl-Shift-PgDn/PgUp default actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to use these actions to perform something specific. They go along with comparable uses for Ctrl-Shift-Down/Up and Ctrl-Shift-End/Home.

The default FF behaviour of Ctrl-Shift-PgDn/PgUp is to shift the current tab to one position to the right/left.

With many other FF hotkey combos I've been able to successfully cancel built-in functionality by going

```
jqElement.on( 'keydown', function( e ){
        const eventCode = e.originalEvent.code;
        if( e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && ! e.altKey && ( eventCode === 'Numpad3' || eventCode === 'PageDown' )){
            e.preventDefault();
            // e.stopPropagation();
        }
```

... in fact `preventDefault` seems to do the trick usually, but in this case I also tried with `stopPropagation`.  Neither worked.

I assume these hotkey combos are too heavily baked-in to the FF key capture mechanism: they're probably intercepting these keystrokes before JQuery even gets to them.  OTOH it may be something actually within JQuery code ...

Reading the JQuery [documentation for on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) led me to do numerous experiments attaching key event handlers using not only "keydown" but also "keyup" and "keypress"... and to the very first elements which would be intercepting the keystroke (before "bubbling up").  Nothing worked.

PS a "workaround" involving an FF add-on, would be of interest, though it's not going to endear me to someone when I say that such-and-such an FF add-on will stop something annoying happening.  But in fact, to date, I haven't found even that: Saka, actually mentioned on the FF "key bindings" page, appears only capable of *adding* bindings... and KeyBinder, which I've just tried, doesn't list these two particular bindings.

PPS I've now just found that Ctrl-PgDn/PgUp are also "baked-in"! These take you away from your current tab to an adjacent one!

Comment: Certain shortcuts, or more precisely certain actions a short cut is asssinged to, are protected on purpose and cannot be prevented.

Comment: Thanks.  I've quickly googled {Firefox "protected actions"} and {Firefox "protected shortcuts"}... notthing very enlightening came up... anywhere where I might read up on that? PS I have to say it would be odd for the FF designers to go out of their way to hinder "customisation" in this way: what's so special about a command which shifts the tab to the right/left that users might not want to use it for something else? Sigh.

Comment: I'm not award that there is a list about that, for chromium I know that there is this function [browser_command_controller.cc: IsReservedCommandOrKey](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/65.0.3290.2/chrome/browser/ui/browser_command_controller.cc#166) which does that check. Maybe the tab movement counts as accessibility functionality and is protected as of that.

Comment: @t.niese ah, right... well as someone who hates being forced to use the mouse I wouldn't want people to be deprived of familiar L&F hotkey functions so... fair enough maybe.